# How to parse a JSON object and display the value as a string on the screen?

Tags: javascript, json

Currently I'm send the following with JSON

{"John":[{"Coins":"600","First_name":"John"}]}

I doubt the line break should be there. I want to take the value of the coins in this case 600 and display it in a div.

```
function importCoins(str) {

    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {


        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            alert(xmlhttp.response);

            data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);
            receivedData(data);

        }
    }

     function receivedData(data) {
     document.write(data.Coins);
     };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://server/~name/folder/extractUser.php");
    xmlhttp.responseType = "json";
    xmlhttp.send();
}

importCoins();
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
include("mysqlconnect.php");

$query  = "SELECT Coins, First_name  FROM users WHERE Id = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$data = array();

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$data[$rows['First_name']][] = $rows;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: That `<br/> ` prefix invalidates your _JSON_. After fixing that, you are sending this as the response to an _XMLHttpRequest_?

Comment: It was in my PHP file. The </br> is not being sent anymore thank you

Answer (score 1):

> and display it in a div

Assuming you have a `<div id="my_target"></div>` in your *HTML*, setting **text** in it can be done as

```
var elm = document.getElementById('my_target'); // HTMLElement or null
elm.textContent = 'foo'; // set it's text to "foo"
```

This will only work **after the *Element* exists**. In other words, you need to wait for the page to finish loading or only initiate this code in a `<script>` tag after the close tag of the element

---

Now, say you have an *JavaScript Object* `var o = {bar: 'baz'};`, you can access it's properties like this

```
o['bar']; // "baz" (the value by accessing _key_ "bar" from _Object_ o
```

If you don't know the *keys* in an *Object*, you can do `for..in` loop over them

```
var key;
for (key in o) {
    console.log(key, o[key]); // logs "bar" "baz"
}
```

---

To wait for the current page to finish loading before invoking something, listen for the *load* event on the *Window Object*

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // code to invoke after page has loaded
});
```

---

Finally, when using *XMLHttpRequest* to fetch JSON, you have inbuilt methods to parse it for you automatically, so you can get a *JavaScript Object* at the end.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = 'GET',
    url = "http://server/~name/folder/extractUser.php";
xhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    // code to invoke after receiving response
    console.log(this.response); // let's log the object
});
xhr.open(method, url);
xhr.responseType = 'json'; // let the request know to expect JSON
xhr.send();
```

---

Putting it all together;

```
function getJSON(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        method = 'GET';
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        callback(this.response);
    });
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.send();
}

function displayCoins(obj) {
    var elm = document.getElementById('my_target');
    elm.textContent = obj["John"][0]["Coins"];
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () { // wait for page to load
    // then invoke it
    getJSON("http://server/~name/folder/extractUser.php", displayCoins);
});
```

---

Final note; **always check your *Console* output** when you encounter a problem with *JavaScript* or are debugging. This gives you much more information and usually will let you spot the problem, if not know which error message to google.

---

> I'm struggling to adjust your final solution in order to fit in `var key; for (key in o) { console.log(key, o[key]); // logs "bar" "baz" }` Could you edit your completed solution to have unknown keys

I didn't include this because I didn't know the behaviour you wanted if there were many keys in your *Object* or just the one. I'll assume just one for this example;

Put the `for..in` loop in the `displayCoins` *function*

```
function displayCoins(obj) {
    var elm = document.getElementById('my_target'),
        key;
    for (key in obj) {
        elm.textContent = obj[key][0]["Coins"];
        break; // stop after first key
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, how can I use the obj["John"[0]["Coins"]] as I don't know it's John till the JSON is sent. I adapted your code but I get a blank screen. I updated my code to show you my PHP and hopefully you'll see what I'm sending.

Comment: I gave an example of how to find unknown keys using `for..in`

Comment: I'm struggling to adjust your final solution in order to fit in   **var key;
for (key in o) {
    console.log(key, o[key]); // logs "bar" "baz"
}** Could you edit your completed solution to have unknown keys

Comment: @moss I've appended a solution I believe will work to my answer. If you're doing this though, it may in fact be better to change the data structure before/as you generate your _JSON_ rather than by the client after

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it to a `variable` and do:

```
var a = {"John":[{"Coins":"600","First_name":"John"}]};
console.log(a.John[0].Coins);     //"600"
```